# Very slow to open Outlook on Parallels 8 with Windows 7 on OS X 10.8.5

Tags: ms-office, parallels-desktop

When I wake my MacBook Air after being in sleep mode, and open Outlook 2010, it can take 30+ seconds to open. This is a relatively new phenomenon.

My system is a MacBook Air (i5 and 8GBs memory) running Windows 7 using Parallels 8.

Comment: You are running Outlook under Win7/in the VM I assume? Are any other applications open/running (either on OS X or in the VM)? Did you try restarting the VM/rebooking the MBA already?

Comment: Safari may or may not be running. It seems to be a problem after lengthy periods of sleep/hibernation.

Comment: I had some issues with Parallels performance in the past, especially when memory on OS X run low. Did you check Activity Monitor?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what I would be looking for. It says I have 2.83GB free; 3.54 Wired;1.39 Active; 244.9MB Inactive. Swap used 4GB and the VM size is 284.95 GB +/-.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled most of the Outlook Add-Ins, and the issue seems to have been resolved. The only Add-In I use is the one for Exchange to work properly.
thx-